# How to generate itertools product without duplicates and symmetric?

Tags: python, combinations, product, python-itertools

I know there is a very similar question: Itertools product without repeating duplicates

but I have something different. For example:

```
a = ['add', 'sub']
b = [2,3, 'a', 'b']
c = [1,3, 'a', 'c']
list(it.product(a, b, c))  # result is:[('add', 2, 1),('add', 2, 3),('add', 2, 'a'), ('add', 2, 'c'),
#('add', 3, 1),('add', 3, 3),('add', 3, 'a'),('add', 3, 'c'),('add', 'a', 1),('add', 'a', 3),
#('add', 'a', 'a'),('add', 'a', 'c'), ('add', 'b', 1),('add', 'b', 3),('add', 'b', 'a'),
#('add', 'b', 'c'),('sub', 2, 1),('sub', 2, 3),('sub', 2, 'a'),('sub', 2, 'c'),('sub', 3, 1),
#('sub', 3, 3),('sub', 3, 'a'),('sub', 3, 'c'),('sub', 'a', 1),('sub', 'a', 3),('sub', 'a', 'a'),
#('sub', 'a', 'c'),('sub', 'b', 1),('sub', 'b', 3),('sub', 'b', 'a'),('sub', 'b', 'c')]
```

for the result:

I don't want `add(a,a)`, as the first value == second value.

I want to keep only 1 of `add(3,a)`, `add(a,3)`, as it is symmetric.

and my example only contains two list, but I may use 5 or more lists to generate product.

I cant use `combinations`, because:

`product(['add', 'sub', 1,2,3, 'a','b', 'c'], repeat=3)` is different with `product(['add', 'sub'], [2,3, 'a', 'b'], [1,3, 'a', 'c'])`

Something in `product(['add', 'sub', 1,2,3, 'a','b', 'c'], repeat=3)` is not ok for me.

I want a fast method, since my program is time sensitive.

Comment: `add(3,a)` and `add(a,3)` are symmetric, but does the same hold for `'sub'` (assuming these are the known functions)?

Comment: @Tomerikoo  yes, i view them as same, i am trying to generate meaningful expr automatically. sub(a, 2) and sub(2, a) is same for me. because it provides no extra meaning. and thanks for editing the question, my gramma is not good

Comment: Can you have `('add', 'c', 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain

a = ['add', 'sub']
b = [2, 3, 'a', 'b']
c = [1, 3, 'a', 'c']

for operation, operands in product(a, combinations(set(chain(b, c)), r=2)):
    print((operation, *operands))
```

**Output**

```
('add', 1, 2)
('add', 1, 3)
('add', 1, 'a')
('add', 1, 'b')
('add', 1, 'c')
('add', 2, 3)
('add', 2, 'a')
('add', 2, 'b')
('add', 2, 'c')
('add', 3, 'a')
('add', 3, 'b')
('add', 3, 'c')
('add', 'a', 'b')
('add', 'a', 'c')
('add', 'b', 'c')
('sub', 1, 2)
('sub', 1, 3)
('sub', 1, 'a')
('sub', 1, 'b')
('sub', 1, 'c')
('sub', 2, 3)
('sub', 2, 'a')
('sub', 2, 'b')
('sub', 2, 'c')
('sub', 3, 'a')
('sub', 3, 'b')
('sub', 3, 'c')
('sub', 'a', 'b')
('sub', 'a', 'c')
('sub', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: That's what I was going for... According to the clarifications in the comments, seems like the most sensible thing to do

Comment: product, combinations, chain ... nice combo :)